# Illustrator acts weird

Tags: adobe-illustrator, pen-tool, anchor-point

I am having a bit of trouble of Illustrator, I do not know if things that are happening are caused by me checking an option or anything else.

So look at this image:
[image]

All of anchor points of rectangles and circles are aligned, and lie on each other perfectly.

Now the problem come when I use either Shape builder tool or pathfinder tool:

Paths become ragged. Anchor points move themselves for no known reason when I merge objects, and it makes it impossible for me to continue to merge or delete some elements.

This is the result I get:
[image]

The truth is I've never worked with Shape Builder Tool before so I could be doing something terribly wrong, so please if you know what's the problem it would be a great help to me!

Comment: Not possible. Please upload your AI artwork so we can inspect.

Comment: In my personal experience, I seem to have less of these kinda problems when sticking with traditional pathfinder options rather than the shape builder tool

Comment: Uncheck Align to Pixel Grid.

Comment: Switch to fills only, no stroke and do your aligning again, then combine with the pathfinder tools.

Answer (score 2):

STEP BY STEP SOLUTION:

**No strokes and work in outline mode for perfect results!**

1. Check it thoroughly for no extra shapes to be made. Use align tools for this.
   [image]

2.
Select all the shapes. then <kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd> (shape builder tool)

3.
[image]

4.
Build the shape you want at once.
[image]

5. You will see this.
   [image]
6. Drag your shape away from the rest pieces.
   [image]
7. Your desired output.
   [image]

Comment: I have eventually figured out that what causing problem is checked option to make new objects snap to grid, but thank you anyway!

Comment: No problem :)  That option makes awful things happen to the vector at times!